# Ajax with polymorphic association (destroy)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic association with Resources & Flags in my rails app. Each Resource can be Flagged by a user.

I am trying to delete resource Flags through its Edit Page. This way a user can edit a Resource, and eliminate/destroy its Flags via ajax.

Everything works fine in the database, but when I try to delete a Flag using ajax, it doesn't work unless unless I refresh the page. I am using this [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised?autoplay=true).

This is my code...

**Models**

```
class Resource 
  belongs_to :district
  has_many :flags, as: :flaggable, :dependent => :destroy  
end 

class Flag 
    belongs_to :flaggable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**Controllers**

```
Resource Controller

  #edit page
  def edit
    @district = District.find_by_abbreviation(params[:district_id])
    @resource = @district.resources.find(params[:id])   
    @flaggable = @resource
    @flags = @resource.flags.all 
  end

end

Flags Controller

  def destroy
    @flag = Flag.find(params[:id])
    @flaggable = @flag.flaggable
    if @flag.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @flaggable }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

end
```

**Views**

edit.html.erb - Resource Edit Page

```
#renders all flags associated with this resource
<div id="flags">
  <%= render @flags %>
</div>

<div>
   #Code that holds edit form
</div>
```

_flag.html.erb

```
###delete action to destroy a flag
<div id="dom_id(flag)">

  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true"><%= link_to '&times;'.html_safe, [@flaggable, flag], method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this flag?" }, remote: true  %></span>
  </button>

  <%= flag.message %>
</div>
```

destroy.js.erb

```
###I am not sure if this is correct...
$('#flags #<%= dom_id(@flag) %>').remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your partial `_flag.html.erb`

It should be `<div id="<%= dom_id(flag) %>">` instead of `<div id="dom_id(flag)">`

Comment: Glad I could help.